# Vue router id gets undefined when taken from vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, router

I am trying to get the id of currently logged user from Vuex getters and pass it into the router link, but somehow it gets undefined, even though I console.log it and it shows legitimate user ID.  In my template. Here I loop over an array of objects where I keep my route name:

```html
<v-list dark class="mt-5 userList" style="background: #515151;">
            <v-list-item
                    v-for="item in sideBar"
                    :key="item.title"
                    class="tile"
            >
                <router-link :to="item.route">
                    <span class="userIcon">
                        <v-list-item-icon>
                                <v-icon style="color: #FFA255">{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                        </v-list-item-icon>
                    </span>

                    <span class="userTitle">
                        <v-list-item-content>
                            <v-list-item-title style="color: #FFA255">
                                {{ item.title }}
                            </v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item-content>
                    </span>
                </router-link>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
```

I think this part speaks for itself My script section:

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            userParams: null,
            sideBar: [
                {title: 'User', icon: 'note', component: 'UserInfo', route: `/user/${this.userParams}`},
                {title: 'Rated albums', icon: 'note', component: 'Rated', route: `/user/${this.userParams}/rated`},
                {title: 'Owned', icon: 'favorite', component: 'Owned', route: `/user/${this.userParams}/owned`},
                {title: 'Settings', icon: 'settings', component: 'Settings', route: `/user/'${this.userParams}'/settings`},
            ],
        }
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'getUserId'
        ])
    },


    created() {
        this.userParams = this.getUserId;
        console.log(this.userParams)
    },
}
```

My router.js

```js
{
        path: '/user/:id',
        component: User,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/',
                component: UserInfo,
                name: 'userInfo'
            },
            {
                path: 'owned',
                component: Owned,
                name: 'owned'
            },
            {
                path: 'rated',
                component: Rated,
                name: 'rated'
            },
            {
              path: 'settings',
              component: Settings,
                name: 'settings'
            }
        ],
        beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
            if(authStore.state.idToken) {
                next()
            } else {
                next('/signin')
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: @Phil could you provide sample code?

Comment: I've moved my comment into an answer below. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `sideBar` a computed property so it is re-evaluated when `getUserId` changes.

I don't see a reason to keep a copy of `getUserId` in `userParams` either.

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([ 'getUserId' ]),
  sideBar () {
    const params = { id: this.getUserId } // this is reactive
    return [{
      title: 'User', 
      icon: 'note', 
      route: { name: 'userInfo', params }
    }, {
      title: 'Rated albums', 
      icon: 'note', 
      route: { name: 'rated', params }
    }, {
      title: 'Owned', 
      icon: 'favorite', 
      route: { name: 'owned', params }
    }, {
      title: 'Settings', 
      icon: 'settings', 
      route: { name: 'settings', params }
    }]
  }
},
```

At the moment, your `route` strings are only calculated once when your component is created

Comment: @rottenbanana You're welcome. I hope you don't mind I changed to using your routes by name. I find it much easier to work with the route objects that way